# phpexcel number format with optional decimal separator

Tags: yii, phpexcel

I am developing a report system using yii and phpexcel. It works nice. Just, one small problem, my client wants to have number format with these rules:

- must have thousand separator
  = may have decimal separator (decimal separator only applied to decimal numbers. number without decimal will only have thousand separators applied).

my current solution:

$formatNumber = '#,##0.##;Red';

I also tried $formatNumber = '#,###.##;Red';

The result almost perfect. Just the "." (decimal separator) is there when the number is a whole number. For example 4020 => written as **4020.**  I do not want the **.** at the end.

Thanks for your help.

Daniel

Comment: Work out how you'd do it in MS Excel itself, and then apply the same mask

Comment: Hi, I could not find any ways to do that in excel. It seems thousand can be optional if the value is not reaching the thousands but not the case for decimals.

Comment: If it can't be done in MS Excel, then PHPExcel can't do it either